# Doing a empty post request with express.json

Tags: node.js

If I try to make an empty request, I do not send data in json format, type json with the header application / json gives this in the form of html, I have to know how to solve it since it shows routes and more things

Im using app.use(express.json())

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:160:10)
    at parse (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at invokeCallback (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:231:16)
    at done (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:220:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:280:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
```

if i use if(Object.keys(req.body).length === 0)

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at file:///D:/Programacion/VUEJS_NODEJS/backend/index.js:71:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at serveStatic (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Programacion\VUEJS_NODEJS\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
```

Solve the code error with express

Answer (score 0):

If you send `application/json` as the `content-type`, then the body MUST be legal JSON.  End of story.  `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` means it wasn't legal JSON.

If you're not sending JSON,then don't set the `content-type` to `application/json` and then `express.json()` won't try to process it.

Or, if you really want it to be `application/json` but don't have any data to send, then send an empty object as the JSON.